# PayPal checkout(v2) with react SDK

Tags: reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating PayPal checkout with react using SDK. The seller currency is USD. I am testing it with an Indian sandbox account. The transaction is successful with all other accounts except for Indian Accounts. In all other cases, the sandbox does the currency conversion and pays the amount accordingly except in Indian currency which says the **seller doesn't accept payment in your currency**. What might be the possible issue? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Go to Wallet -> Details -> Manage currencies. Are there any rules listed for balance or payment conversion which could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with sandbox account created. This account was created to accept payment in an only particular currency. The problem got resolved by using other sandbox business account which accepts payment in all currencies.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is explained [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/currency-codes/) in footnote (3) for INR.

> "This currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency
> balance for in-country PayPal India accounts only."